# iOS TCP socket losing connection for some customers

Tags: ios, sockets, tcp

I have an app that creates a TCP socket and receives data from different kinds of hardware. The majority of my customers are happy users, but some have the problem that the TCP connection is interrupted after some time (could be 30 seconds or 5 minutes).

I'm using the CFStreamCreatePairWithSocketToHost - approach, and do all my handling in the "handleEvent" method.

I've got some customers loggings of the failure, and I get this event:

> ErrorOccurred "The operation couldn’t be completed. Socket is not
>   connected (Code = 57)"

After a couple of successful reconnections I might get this event when I try to reconnect:

> ErrorOccurred "The operation couldn’t be completed. No route to host
>   (Code = 65)"

The easy explanation would be that their devices that create the WiFi network and stream the data are bad, but some customers are also using other apps that connects to the same devices, and those apps don't lose their connections.

I'm running out of ideas what to change or improve to solve the problem.

I've checked that the size of the data available, and it's never more than 1 sentence, so it's not like any buffers are running full.

I actually also have a small test app that does nothing but connect to the broadcasting device and log the received data - and that also loses the connection for these customers.

I also tried to use `AsyncSocket` instead but I am having the same problem.

My hairs are turning grey... :-) Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: The connection is interrupted with a code 57 (Socket is not connected). Often the app is able to reconnect within a second, but sometimes the reconnect fails with an error 65 (No route to host). This error (65) repeats for a while and then might change to error code 22 (Invalid argument). After a while the reconnect attempt changes to error code 54 (Connection reset by peer). After that it will go on for a while with a mix of error code 22 and 54 and eventually end with an error code 60 (Operation timed out). After that reconnection is successful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A lot of testing, logging and speculating finally solved the case.
The only thing the customer had to do was to lower the baud rate, and the problem disappeared.

Case closed.

Comment: I have 13 bytes of data to read and write, And having 9600 Baud rate but I am still getting the same issue as you are getting. Is there any better way?